# PKCS12 generation for ECC key types using JavaScript

Tags: rsa, ecc

I'm generating p12 for ECC key types using the Forge library. https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/777

This library already provides p12 for RSA key types; now, I'm trying to enhance to ECC key types.

I'm generating a private key in PEM format, certificates into an ASN.1 format private key. Here I've written ECPrivateValidator to validate and convert the private key into ASN.1 format.

```
name: 'PrivateKeyInfo',
  class: asn1.Class.UNIVERSAL,
  tag: asn1.Type.SEQUENCE,
  capture: 'privateKeyInfo',
  value: [{
    name: 'PrivateKeyInfo.Version',
    class: asn1.Class.UNIVERSAL,
    tag: asn1.Type.INTEGER,
    capture: 'privateKeyVersion'
  }]
}
```

Can you guide me if you have any thoughts on it?